# Testing AngularJS Service that uses $routeParams as a URL parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am using Jasmine to test my services. One of my services uses $routeParams as a URL parameter. Now when I test, $routeParams becomes undefined

this is my service code

```
    this.getProjectFunction = function (options) {
                $http.get(rootUrl + $routeParams.projectName)
                        .success(options.success)
                        .error(options.error);
            };
```

And this is how my test looks like

```
describe('App Service', function() {

    describe('App Service Tests', function(){

        var httpBackend, service, optionsSpy, routeParams;

        var returnData = [{"id":1,"name":"test"];

        beforeEach( module( 'appName' ) );

        beforeEach(
            inject(
                function($httpBackend,projectService,routeParams) {
                    service = projectService;
                    optionsSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('optionsSpy',['success','error','data']);
                    routeParams = $routeParams;
                    httpBackend = $httpBackend;

                }
            )
        );

         afterEach(function() {
           httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
           httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
        });


            //this should get a specific project
            it('should call the getAllProjectsFunction function that will return an argument array',

                           function(){

                               //set up some data for the http call to return and test later.
                               httpBackend.whenGET('../'+routeParams.projectName).respond(returnData);
                               service.getProjectFunction(optionsSpy);

                               httpBackend.flush();                            
                               expect(optionsSpy.success.mostRecentCall.args[0]).toBe(returnData);
                           }
            );
    });
});
```

Im new to Jasmine testing. Thanks for the help have a good day :)

Comment: inject(function($httpBackend,projectService,__routeParams__) ...)

You're injecting the wrong service

Answer (score 3):

You need to inject `$routeParams` not `routeParams`, and then you can set `routeParams.projectName = 'foo';` then set up `httpBackend.whenGET('../foo').respond(returnData);` (`../foo` may need to be more like `/foo`  since I don't think the "up one folder" command works here.)